# Is there a way to determine if a payment intent's charge has been successfully transferred into your stripe account?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm adding a payout to connected partner accounts through stripe, while I can easily get if they have a payment intent and check if it has succeeded I can't determine if that succeeded payment intent is in the stripe account for payout yet.

I tried using `stripe.balance.retrieve();` but this doesn't tell me which payment intents have succeeded and transferred into the stripe account balance for payout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by looking at Balance Transaction [status](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-status) of a Charge. If the status is `available`, it means the fund is ready in account balance for payout.

To retrieve the Balance Transaction status of a Charge, you can expand the `latest_charge.balance_transaction` field using [Payment Intent Retrieval API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve). For example,

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_xxx \
  -u sk_test_xxx: \
  -d "expand[]"="latest_charge.balance_transaction"
```

Comment: yep that works, thank you! But is it possible for latest_charge to be a refund or something other than a balance transaction into the stripe account?

Answer (score -2):

Basically, you can't.

After all, you can with some alternatives ways.

If you put in payment intents metadata the date where payments will be available (the date depend of Stripe configuration, 7 or 3 days), you'll be able to know which payments is in your Stripe balance.

Thanks to metadata, you can edit them manually or with an API call when creating payment intent.